# Delay in CSS :active selector taking effect

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my CSS 3 button to operate properly. You can view the button at [one of my project pages](http://nova-fusion.com/projects/strong/). The problem is that there's a second or so delay before the `:active` CSS selector takes effect, making the button move slightly and changing the shadow; it didn't do this before. Here's the Sass code:

```
@mixin transition($type, $time, $ease) {
  -webkit-transition: $type $time $ease;
  transition: $type $time $ease;
}

@mixin border-radius($length) {
  border-radius: $length;
  -webkit-border-radius: $length;
  -moz-border-radius: $length;
}

.project-download {
  color: #000300;
  background-color: #00910A;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;

  @include transition(background-color, 0.2s, linear);
  @include border-radius(10px);

  box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  -webkit-box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  -moz-box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  &:hover { background-color: #00B00C; }
  &:active {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;    
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
  }
}
```

which translates in CSS to:

```
.project-download {
  color: #000300;
  background-color: #00910A;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;

  box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  -webkit-box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  -moz-box-shadow:
    1px 1px 0 0 #014D06,
    2px 2px 0 0 #014D06,
    3px 3px 0 0 #014D06,
    4px 4px 0 0 #014D06,
    5px 5px 5px 0 #000000;

  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;

  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.project-download:active {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;    
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #000000;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}

.project-download:hover { background-color: #00B00C; }
```

I've searched Google a bit with no luck. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
I solved the problem that Clicky was causing by using this JavaScript function:

```
function removeLinkListeners()
{
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  {
    if (links[i].classList.contains('project-download-link'))
    {
      links[i].removeEventListener('mousedown', clicky.outbound);
    }
  }
}
```

And changing the initialisation script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try
{
  clicky.init(234973);
  window.onload = removeLinkListeners;
}
catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Comment: didnt see anything wrong

Comment: @Ibu Which browser? And did you have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: i am using safari right now, on an old powerbook g4 Mac os 10.4 and there is no delay

Comment: @Ibu That's strange. I tested it in Safari and I got the same delay. But as you might notice, if you have JavaScript disabled, there won't be any delay.

Comment: maybe you should review your javascript

Comment: @Ibu Have you taken a look at my comment on the answer below? I've identified the script causing it.

Comment: oh good then . so it works when u disable it right?

Comment: @Ibu Indeed it does. But I can't take out my tracking code; I'll have to find a way to turn that feature off.

Comment: Usually you dont have much control on third party scripts. you should read their documentation for a better solution

Comment: @Ibu Yeah, but I might be able to remove the event listeners via JavaScript of something.

Comment: then you wont have any reason to have the tracking code in the first place. why dont you give a try to google analytics. it uses asynchronous code that you wont even notice. and for tracking downloads or any event it has the event tracker that is very well documented and easy to use

Comment: I don't you got what I meant. I meant, remove the event listeners from the link's click event. That only stops a single feature of the tracking code, everything else is kept intact. And yes, I've tried Google Analytics; for me, Clicky is far better.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Why did you remove the "css3". This thing uses a good amount of CSS3 in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place your code in a jsfiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/zfFtv/

You will notice there is no delay. So I'm suspecting it's your javascript. Perhaps the getclicky code is not efficient and causes a delay when you click on it? Try disabling your js files one by one to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yep, it's my Clicky tracking code. It seems to be sending out a request every time I click the button, probably for tracking link clicking. Now to work out how to turn that off.